# Alexa Development Console Python, Make Alexa Speak Without User Response

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I am trying to make an Alexa program in python using the Alexa Development Console. I want Alexa to be able to speak without user response. Like, if the program gets a notification from a server, I want Alexa to immediately speak. However, currently, my python code only allows Alexa to speak only when the user says something.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. You cannot make Alexa say something without the user explicitly triggering it. The only exceptions are Reminders and Proactive Notifications.